# Converting a somewhat organized text file to csv using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text

I need to convert a text file to csv and organize it by columns. However, my data in the text file is by rows, and is 715 pages long. Below is an example of what the text file looks like:

This is an example of what my data looks like, but in reality there is a lot more information per person and there are thousands of entries.

[image]

Basically, each row is separated by "-------". However, the data between the rows are in multiple lines. For example, there will be --- and then name and age on the next line and then salary on the line after and then another --- to signify the start of a new entry.

Is there a way where I can somehow work around this weird layout of data to end up with a csv with columns such as name, age, occupation, salary, etc. I'd be using python. I was thinking, would it be possible to maybe split it by the ---- symbol that precedes each new row? I'm not sure how to go about this though, and I am very beginner. Or if python may not be the best way to do it, what is?

Comment: Please include the text from the file you have as an image as actual text.

Comment: Post the example as text here in the question so we can copy/paste. Yes you can use the dashes to break out the data. I'd likely turn to `itertools.groupby` for that. You can use it to create subiterators for the lines between the dashes. I'd focus on converting the file to a list and do the `pandas` stuff later.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Don't use images, unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to create subiterators that alternate between dashed lines and non-dashed lines. Now the non-dash iterators are just the blocks of text. Assuming that these fields are separated either by at least one tab character or multipel whitespace characters, a regular expression can carve them up.

```
import itertools

def get_my_data(filename):
    data = []
    with open(filename) as fileobj:
        for is_dash, block_iter in itertools.groupby(
                fileobj, lambda line: line.startswith("------")):
            if not is_dash:
                row = []
                for line in block_iter:
                    cols = [cell.strip() for cell in
                        re.split(r"\t+|\s{2,}", line)]
                    row.extend(cols)
                if row:
                    data.append(row)
```

Comment: what kind of expression can i use to carve it up? also, how can i view what the final product looks like?

Comment: I used a regular expression `r"\t+|\s{2,}"` that uses one or more tabs, or any 2 or more spaces in a row to carve each line into parts. That was just a guess, since I don't know what is really being used in your data.